# DllNotFoundException in Firebase when trying to run an Android project exported from Unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm exporting an Android project from Unity (target API 25) and integrating it into another Android project. This native app invokes the project exported from Unity.

The Unity app uses Firebase database. As soon as the Initialization code runs, I get a DllNotFoundException. I just get the following log on loop:

> 01-10 22:26:16.256 12625 13402 E Unity   : DllNotFoundException: App
>   01-10 22:26:16.256 12625 13402 E Unity   :   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
>
> 01-10 22:26:16.256 12625 13402 E Unity   :   at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in :0
>   01-10 22:26:16.256 12625 13402 E Unity   : Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for SWIGExcepti

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Assets** -> **Play Services Resolver**-> **Android Resolver** -> **Resolve**

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is already closed, but I would like to pass on my experience, I had the same problem, and I was able to solve it as follows.
After you export the Unity3d project to Android Studio, convert it to module

Removing the project's applicationId in build.gradle
Changing com.android.application to com.android.library in build.gradle

1 - Copy the .aar files from the .libs folder of the module project, if the master project does not already have them
2 - include the .aar files in build.gradle

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree (include: ['* .jar', '* .aar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation project (': ModuleApp')

---

}

3 - Copy the file "google-services.xml" to the res / values / google-services.xml folder of the master project
4 - Ready, Firebase will work with the sources of the module exported from Unity

Sorry for my bad english